# Does the Bladesinger's Song of Victory grant the Int bonus without TWF Style?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting, fighting-style

Do bladesingers apply the *song of victory* Int modifier to the two-weapon fighting bonus attack, or do they still need the two-weapon fighting style?

I know that you don't add the ability modifier that you use for the attack to the damage, but what about ability modifier from other features?  Is this a case RAI vs RAW?

Does *song of victory* need to say apply a **bonus** equal to the Int modifier for the bonus attack to benefit from it?

Sometimes I wish 5e has better wording on features.

Two Weapon Fighting

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand. **You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.**

Answer (score 11):

This is a situation of "general vs. specific". The general rules for two weapon fighting are:

1. Main weapon must be light.
2. Off-hand weapon must be light.
3. Off-hand weapon doesn't get the normal attribute bonus to damage.

These are all specific rules that override the general rules about making a melee weapon attack based on a single extra condition: "when you put a weapon in your second hand".

There are even more specific rules, ones with *multiple* conditions - "when you put a weapon in your second hand *and* have ________". More qualifying conditions fits the definition of something being more specific.

- The "Dual Wielder" feat provides specific rules that overrides the first two.
- The "Two-Weapon Fighting" style (Fighters, et. al.) provides specific rules that overrides the third.

"Song of Victory" is a specific rule that applies an additional bonus to *all* melee weapon attack damage rolls. It does not cite any restrictions about main hand vs. off hand, so no restrictions apply to it. The fact that value is equal to an attribute is irrelevant - it could be a static value, and it wouldn't change things.

Comment: Well, I guess if you count “Song of Victory” as a specific rule that overrides the general rule of two-weapon fighting then it make sense.

Comment: @Polo Minor tweak to point out the fact that more qualifying conditions is the definition of being more specific.